# Save WebView on Load of another Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I have a webview and i load it with an external URL so this loads the First page and i click on a link goes to the second page then i click on the third page .

Now on this third page i have written a Javascript to open Another Activity which works fine .
But on close of this Activity my WebView reloads the First page again which should had rather been same page where the Activity was called ..??

Any idea as to What is it that i am doing wrong ?

Thanks in Advance.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.R.bool;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class Cam2 extends Activity {
    int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2;

    WebView webview;
    String imageSource;
    boolean _hasImage = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final Activity activity = this;
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            }
        });
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (_hasImage) {
                    webview.loadUrl("javascript:AndroidSubmitToWeb();");
                }
            }
        });

        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.5/SomeWeb");
    }

    public void openCamera() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            String s = storeAndExit(thumbnail);
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:function ImageData(){ return '" + s
                    + "';}");
            _hasImage = true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Cam2.this, "Picture Not taken", 5000).show();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public String storeAndExit(Bitmap data) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream jpeg_data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap myMap = data;
        try {
            if (myMap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, jpeg_data)) {
                byte[] code = jpeg_data.toByteArray();
                byte[] output = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
                        .encodeBase64(code);
                String js_out = new String(output);
                return js_out;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Cam2.this,
                    "STORE IMAGE EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage(), 5000).show();
        }
        finish();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please check whether onCreate() is  called again while you exiting from your second activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should in the onCreate() mnethod

that web view already created & displays the web pages.

only you need to check this thats all.

Best Regards,

~Anup

Comment: U mean i have to check if the WebView is Created if created then do nothing else load URL right ?

Comment: are you destroying your first activity while creating another if yes please dont do that

Comment: Hi Anup, Thanks for helping me out i have edited my post along with the code .I am Beginner to Android